# What is the “clip ring” part on my hubs?

Tags: hub, vintage

I recently bought a vintage Japanese Zunow road bicycle from the 1980's. The Sunshine hubs comes with small little rusty “clip rings” on both sides. Any idea what is the purpose of those clips?

[image: my clips]

[image: similar setup seen on web]

Comment: Are they loose to rotate or are they a firm clip-fit?  Could be hub cleaners if loose, or perhaps just temporarily clipped on there from somewhere else.  They may not even be parts from the bike.

Comment: Could be a clip for some kind of light?  But back then lights were incandescent with fairly weak batteries which needed size to increase capacity, not the modern LED with tiny wee lithium batteries we can fit anywhere today.

Answer (score 9):

Is there a small hole that was covered by the ring? If so it covers a lubrication port. Many old Raleigh, and other utility type hubs came with such a port.

Comment: On a closer look one may spot a dent in the middle of each of those clips - this dent matches the lubrication port you mention which confirms the purpose of those clips even further.

Comment: I don’t see any “lubrication port” however...

Comment: @Sebastien Maybe somebody clipped them on non-holed hubs. Just for show. I once had pre-WW2 hubs which had these oiling openings. Not a good idea anyway. The oil would dilute and wash out the grease in the bearings.

Comment: @Carel might be just it....